# Redirection script

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to write a php script for following...

```
if country = in or ca
redirect_to http://example.com
else redirect to http://example2.com

if $_GET['foo'] = 'bar' and country = in or ca
redirect to http://example3.com

else redirect to example.com
else redirect to example.com
```

and I have tried following...

```
$country = $_SESSION['countrycode'];

//if country india,canada
if($country == 'in' || $country == 'ca') redirect_to('http://example.com/');
else redirect_to('http://example2.com/');

//if querysting contains foo=bar and country india,canada
if($_GET['foo'] == 'bar'){
    if($country == 'in' || $country == 'ca') redirect_to('http://example3.com/');
    else redirect_to('http://example.com/');
}
else redirect_to('http://example.com/');
```

But its not working in case of query string foo = bar. Please suggest.

Comment: Well, what is the value of `$country`?

Comment: @relentless iso code from session like 'in' or 'ca';

Comment: Are you sure it's set? echo `$country` and check the actual value. Also, is `$_GET['foo']` set?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: @relentless everything is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first conditional statement is redirecting the page away from this script. The second conditional statement is never read. Instead, you should refactor something like this:

```
if($country == 'in' || $country == 'ca'){
    if($_GET['foo'] === 'bar')
        header('Location: ' . $urlof3);
    else
        header('Location: '. $urlof2);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Yes.  You need to start with your most specific redirect conditions and follow with most general, otherwise more specific cases will never be reached.